# Removing // from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ipad, nsmutablearray

When I NSLog the contents of an NSMutableArray I get null. I believe I know what the issue is.

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to remove "//" at the beginning of this JSON output. If you load http://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=AAPL,C into your browser you'll see the "//" at the beginning. I believe that the "//" is what is causing the array to return null. How could I go about removing the two dashes? Below is I have what I've done thus far...

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=C,JPM,AIG,AAPL";

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
            [NSURL URLWithString: url]];

//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSMutableArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                  JSONObjectWithData:data //1

                  options:kNilOptions 
                  error:&error];

NSLog(@"json is %@", json); //returns "json is (null)"
```

Comment: In your other post (where you unaccepted my answer), danh showed you in the answer you accepted how to do this.  I'm not sure it will help, because I did that too, and there was another problem character in the middle of the JSON (there could be others as well)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624299/json-returning-null)

Comment: Yes danh, was correct to point out that the issue was the "//" and that somehow I should remove the two dashes. However the solution to remove the dashes did not workout. So its become a question of how to remove the dashes rather than why the data is returning null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
NSData *newData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, [data length] -4)];
```

This gets rid of the first four characters.  There was a control character the two slashes and a space before the first "[", and this gets rid of those.  I tried this but the data still had a flaw in it further on.